# Goto definition not working in vscode for multi-level object like $this->Model->Method()

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCOde and getting one problem for one feature called **goto definition**.

When I am pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*Click* on any Definition it's working and when I am pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+*Click* on `$this->Function()` it also working but when i am pressing **`$this->class->method()`** it's not working (I wanted to open Method function of class).

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: which language are you trying this with (in VSCode the navigate to defintiion feature is provided by a language service)? Also - do you get any errors in the output pane? (View menu then select "Output")

Comment: Language i am using PHP, javascript, JQuery